# Runtime plugins in Rust

Tags: rust

We have a commercially sold application that is presently written in Java and Python.  We are currently looking at moving to Rust for performance and non-crashy reasons.

In our present Java/Python architecture, we have a feature that manages customisations that particular customers want.  This involves placing Java jars/classes and python files under a specific folder designated for customisation for specific customers.  In the application configuration, the Java classpath and the PYTHON_PATH have this folder precede the folders containing the normal, uncustomised application code.  Because of this, any code in this special folder will override the normal, uncustomised behaviour of the application.

We would like to keep this feature in some form when moving to Rust.  We certainly want to avoid distributing source code to our customers for the core app (mostly Java now) and have customers compile, which is what we would need to do if we used Rust's module feature.

Is there a way we can we implement this feature when we go to Rust?

Target OS's are a mix of Linux and Windows.

Comment: Is it an option for you to compile the code yourself for each individual customer?

Comment: @Thomas In relation to the core application code, no.  The core application code is subject to some quite heavy testing, and if we did a separate compile of that for each customer, we would need to do that test work for each customer - too expensive.  The advantage of the present architecture is that the customisations are "on the side", easy to remove, and it keeps the test effort low.

We would be more okay with adding hooks and interface points in the code.

Comment: @Miner_Glitch After the Java JIT runs, you have effectively built a binary per customer already. So testing doesn't sound like a good reason you couldn't do this. Organize all your customer binaries in a [workspace](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/workspaces.html), put the common parts into a library crate, test that heavily, maybe add a few per-binary tests where needed.

Comment: @Caesar The difference is that the JIT is a completely transparent runtime process that runs on the client computer. It has nothing whatsoever to do with the outlined suggestion of customers sending their code to OP, OP compiling it for them, and sending it back to the customers.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Ah, it sounded to me like Miner_Glitch is doing the customization for the customers. (In which case it really wouldn't matter where the final machine code gets produced…)

Comment: On second thought: The option of embedding a wasm engine, and in particular https://extism.org/ probably deserve a mention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you want some kind of plugin architecture, with a dynamic library (also written in Rust) that's loaded at runtime.

Unfortunately, [Rust doesn't have a stable ABI yet](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/a-stable-modular-abi-for-rust/12347/1), meaning that those librarise would have to be compiled with the exact same compiler that built the main application. One workaround is to expose a C ABI from the plugin side, and use C FFI to call it, if you can live with the unsafety and hassle that entails. There's also the [`abi_stable`](https://crates.io/crates/abi_stable) crate, which might be safer/simpler to use.

Scripting languages might be another avenue to explore. For example, [Rhai](https://rhai.rs/) is a language specifically developed for use in Rust applications, and interoperates as seamlessly as these things get. Of course, performance of the scripted parts will not be as great as native Rust code.

Comment: This looks promising, having "dylib"s in our code might be the way to go.

Are you saying that dylib is unstable at the moment?

Comment: No, the `dylib` crate type is stable as far as I know. But the interface (ABI) of the resulting library is not guaranteed to remain the same between Rust compiler versions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it is possible without recompiling it or at least compiling the `config.rs` file that you intend to create for individual users.

Assuming that the end user does not have Rust installed on their system, a few alternatives might be:

- Using `.yaml` files for loading configs (similar to how GitHub Actions work)
- Allowing users to run custom programs (you can use [tokio::process](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/process/struct.Command.html#) to run them in an async manner)
- Using [rhaiscript](https://github.com/rhaiscript/rhai) (I personally prefer this option)

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the official language docs for the [modules feature](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/modules.html)

you could set up your commercial project in such a way that the source code is threated as an external crate, and then load it into the main project with the `path attribute`.

A minimal example, already on the docs:

```
#[path = "thread_files"]
mod thread {
    // Load the `local_data` module from `thread_files/tls.rs` relative to
    // this source file's directory.
    #[path = "tls.rs"]
    mod local_data;
}
```

Comment: This requires customers to compile.  We really want to avoid that.